# Which targets are heavily damaged by Gravity?

Tags: final-fantasy-crystal-chronicles

The spell description for Gravity reads as follows:

> Heavily damages certain targets and cripples flying foes.

What enemies are "certain targets"? The second part is obvious, but I haven't been able to figure out who gets damaged by gravity, rather than just grounded.